# Powershell scripting

Tags: powershell

I want to automate test using powershell. I want to write a script to shutdown the computer, wait for 3minutes and then power on the computer. Is it possible using Powershell? I know that reboot is possible, but I want the system to remain in shutdown stage for 3min and then power on.

Comment: That would only be possible I would think using a WOL solution on a different system. Why 3 minutes? It is possible you are trying to address a different problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can shutdown computer with [`Stop-Computer`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh849839.aspx) command
2. Wait with [`Start-Sleep`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177002.aspx)
3. But to poweron PC you need something more complex, take a look at [`WOL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN). However there are some difficulties:

   - It would work only with PCs that allow to be awakened with magic packets
   - You need to know MAC-address of machine
   - Target machine should be in the current network subnet of the caller.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a "real computer" (not a Virtual Machine) so it's not possible. But you can achieve that using Virtual Machine setup.  Take look at this documentation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848589.aspx